# How to pack csv files having same prefix name into zip in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Assume that I have many csv file located into `/home/user/test`

```
123_24112021_DONG.csv
122_24112021_DONG.csv
145_24112021_DONG.csv
123_24112021_FINA.csv
122_24112021_FINA.csv
145_24112021_FINA.csv
123_24112021_INDEM.csv
122_24112021_INDEM.csv
145_24112021_INDEM.csv
```

As you can see, all files have three unique prefix :

```
145
123
122
```

And, I need to create zip per prefix which will contains csv files. Note that in reality, I dont know the number of csv file, It is just an example (3 csv files per prefix).
I developed a code that extract prefixes from all csv names in bash table :

```
for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do
  # extract csv files
  f1=${entry##*/}
  echo $f1
  # extract prefix of each file
  f2=${f1%%_*}
  echo $f2
  # add prefix in table
  liste_sirets+=($f2)
done

# get uniq prefix in unique_sorted_list

unique_sorted_list=($(printf "%s\n" "${liste_sirets[@]}" | sort -u ))
echo $unique_sorted_list
```

which give the result :

```
145
123
122
```

Now I want to zip each three files defined by their prefix in same zip file :
In other word, create `123_24112021_M2.zip` which will contains

```
123_24112021_DONG.csv
123_24112021_FINA.csv
123_24112021_INDEM.csv
```

and `122_24112021_M2.zip` `145_24112021_M2.zip` ...

So, I developed a loop which will focus on each prefix name of csv files located in local path then zip all having the same prefix name :

```
for i in $unique_sorted_list
do
for j in "$search_dir"/*
do
if $(echo $j| cut -d'_' -f1)==$i
zip -jr $j
done
```

But, it does not work, any help, please ! thank you !

Comment: You could first create an array of different prefixes (use an associative array instead of an indexed array for this purpose). Then, on a second pass, go through this prefix-list and collect all files with this prefix for zipping. You don't need to sort then.

Comment: @user1934428: Indeed that's what I showed in my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using bash and shell utilities:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '%s\n' *_*.csv | cut -d_ -f1 | uniq |
while read -r prefix
do
        zip "$prefix".zip "$prefix"_*.csv
done
```

**Update:**
It is also requested to group files by date (the second part of the filename):

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '%s\n' *_*_*.csv | cut -d_ -f2 | sort -u |
while read -r date
do
        zip "$date".zip ./*_"$date"_*.csv
done
```

Comment: Aydin, thank you !! it works, but I need to add `DATE_M2` to the package name. In other word the zip name will be : `prefix_DATE_M2`.zip

Comment: @SA2018 You can modify the zip command inside the `while` loop: `zip "$prefix"_DATE_M2.zip "$prefix"_*.csv`

Comment: thanks ! and last question, is it possible by this simple shell command to create zip packages in specific path instead of actual one ?

Comment: @SA2018 `zip /path/to/zips/"$prefix"_DATE_M2.zip "$prefix"_*.csv`

Comment: Aydin, thank you very very much !!!

Comment: Aydin, how about if I want to pack only files having same `DATE` value in files's name ? because I need to filter into all csv files by second part also to pack them into same zip file, thanks

Comment: @SA2018 Please read the updated answer.

Comment: thank, you very much

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash 4+` associative arrays:

```sh
# declare an associative array
declare -A unq

# store unique prefixes in array unq
for f in *_*.csv; do
   unq["${f%%_*}"]=1
done

# iterate through unq and create zip files
for i in "${!unq[@]}"; do
   zip "$i" "${i}_"*
done
```

Comment: thant you for your response, but, it does not work, I dont get uniq prefix in uniq array, the second iterate gives `zip error: Nothing to do! (5.zip)
+zip 6 '6_*'`, For information, before your commands, I pointed to the local path which contains csv files : `cd $search_dir`

Comment: It is properly tested solution on my `bash 5.1.8`. What does `declare -p unq` shows after first loop?

Comment: it returns `CreateZip.KSH[638]: declare: not found [No such file or directory]`

Comment: `bash 4.2` should be fine but `declare: not found` means you are probably not using `bash`. Just run `bash` before running this script.

Comment: note that I am using 4.2 version of bash. Then, the second loop should browse all csv file in `$search_dir`, then compare their prefix with uniq values of table. So, I think thant we should add if command for this

Comment: Naming your script "CreateZip.KSH" is only going to cause confusion; consider renaming it to "CreateZip.sh" or "CreateZip.bash", @SA2018. Ensure the first line isn't using ksh (your login shell can be anything, as can the sh-bang line of the script).

Comment: I am obliged to create .KSH file, because X raisons depended on the Unix version deployed in the company. I declared `#!/bin/bash` , and the extension of file which I run is `KSH`

Comment: @anubhava yes I runned  `bash`, there is no return value or specific exception

Comment: `declare` is internal directive of `bash` and `declare: not found` instantly tells us your script is not using `bash`

Comment: well, I did a refresh and now it shows other error : `uniq: full: must use subscript when assigning associative array`, no problem about declare

Comment: ok try my updated code in answer